# PHP Elasticsearch "Set" mapping

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have got an Elastic server (version 2.3.1) up and running and I try to use the official [PHP client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_installation_2.html) to store documents. The structure I create in `PHP`:

```
$data = Array(
  "index"=> "my_index",
  "type" => "my_type",
  "id"   => $my_generated_id,
  "body" => Array(
    "name"        => $name, 
    "other_field" => $other_data,
    "tags"        => array_unique($tags)
  )
);
```

**print_r($data):**

```
Array
(
    [index] => my_index
    [type] => my_type
    [id] => AFCDEFGH
    [body] => Array
        (
            [name] => It is my name
            [other_field] =>  some other information 
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Some tag
                    [2] => Some other tag
                )
        )
)
```

The first document is nicely stored (and it creates the index) but as soon as I try to insert a document with different number of tags I get some error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"object mapping for [tags] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"object mapping for [tags] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"},"status":400} in /home/test/test/php/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:655
```

I know that the index is built up in a wrong way:

```
{
   "my_index":{
      "aliases":{
      },
      "mappings":{
         "targy":{
            "properties":{
               "other_field":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "name":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "tags":{
                  "properties":{
                     "0":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "2":{
                        "type":"string"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings":{
         "index":{
            "creation_date":"1477414478664",
            "number_of_shards":"5",
            "number_of_replicas":"1",
            "uuid":"yZiN4uUgRXe9vyaN4uWbGg",
            "version":{
               "created":"2030199"
            }
         }
      },
      "warmers":{
      }
   }
}
```

How can I build up the mapping in `PHP` manually to be able to handle zero or more tag at the same time? (I think the solution is not to handle this "bag" of `strings` as an `array` but instead of some other datatype which I was looking for the past few days.)

Examples:

```
[tags] => Array
          (
             [0] => Some tag
             [2] => Some other tag
             [3] => Some other tag
          )
//...
[tags] => Array
          (
          )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an array_unique, there are holes in the returned array: In your example there is no item for the key 1. Thus it is indexed as a map by Elasticsearch,
which is not the behavior you want.

Use `array_merge(array_unique($tags))` in your code, this generate an array without holes that will be indexed as such by Elasticsearch.

You will have to delete your index before reindexing to regenerate the mapping ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this way will I be able to store empty or for example 6 tag for a document? I have various counts of tags an I am not able to determine how many of them coud be represented.

Comment: Yes, you will not have limit on the size of the array, and your mapping will stay `"tags": {  type: "string" }`, same as for a string.